# Finite abelian groups acting on smooth varieties and "invariant" invertible functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, complex-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group acting on a smooth quasi-projective variety $X$ over $\mathbb C$.  Let $E(X) = \mathcal{O}(X)^*/\mathbb C^*$.

**Under what conditions is $E(X)^G$ the trivial group?**

One simple condition which implies that $E(X)^G$ is trivial is that $\mathcal{O}(X) = \mathbb C^*$. That certainly implies that $E(X)^G $ is trivial, as it implies that $E(X)$ is trivial. Examples of such varieties are dense open subsets of $\mathbb A^n$ whose complement is of codimension at least two.

There are some other criteria appearing in Knop-Kraft-Vust's paper entitled [*The Picard group of a $G$-variety*](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-0348-7662-9_5) ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1044586) [CiteSeerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.114.2496)).

Are any others known? In other words, are there some nice examples of pairs $(X,G)$ as above with $E(X)^G$ trivial?

Note: I edited the question to make it more and more elementary.

Comment: Note that the second author is "Kraft", and the complete reference is: Friedrich Knop, Hanspeter Kraft, Thierry Vust, *The Picard group of a $G$-variety*. Algebraische Transformationsgruppen und Invariantentheorie, 77–87,  DMV Sem., 13, Birkhäuser, Basel, 1989.